# Unable to run SonarQube 5.3 as a service on Windows

Tags: windows, service, sonarqube, windows-server-2012-r2, sonarqube5.3

I'm unable to run SonarQube 5.3 as a service on Windows Server 2012 or windows 10.  It runs fine using StartSonar.bat but when installed and run as a service there is the error

"**The SonarQube service on Local Computer started then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs**."

I've tried a specific service user with local admin access and the "Local System account" user with the same result.

I have tested starting the service specifying a desktop user with Local Administrator access which works OK but our policy is to use a specific service user for services.

I've tried using JDK 8 64bit and JDK 7 32 bit with the same results

Ther contents of sonar.log are

```
Using tick timer.
--> Wrapper Started as Service
server listening on port 32000.
Launching a JVM...
command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\java.exe" -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms3m -Xmx3m -Djava.library.path="./lib" -classpath "../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar;../../lib/sonar-application-5.3.jar" -Dwrapper.key="Rfo5GpLfYyokZuoo" -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.debug="TRUE" -Dwrapper.pid=7932 -Dwrapper.version="3.2.3" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.service="TRUE" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.sonar.application.App
JVM started (PID=3388)
WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main  Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
Running a 64-bit JVM.
Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.
Loading native library failed: wrapper-windows-x86-64.dll  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-windows-x86-64 in java.library.path
Loaded native library: wrapper.dll
Calling native initialization method.
Initializing WrapperManager native library.
Java Executable: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\java.exe
Windows version: 6.3.9600
Java Version   : 1.8.0_72-b15 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation

Control event monitor thread started.
Startup runner thread started.
WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@4f023edb, args[]) called by thread: main
Communications runner thread started.
Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
Opened Socket from 31000 to 32000
Send a packet KEY : Rfo5GpLfYyokZuoo
handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32000,localport=31000])
accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31000
read a packet KEY : Rfo5GpLfYyokZuoo
Got key from JVM: Rfo5GpLfYyokZuoo
send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
send a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Start Application.
send a packet START : start
Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
PingTimeout from Wrapper is 0
Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Received a packet START : start
calling WrapperListener.start()
Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOP : 0
Startup runner thread stopped.
read a packet STOP : 0
JVM requested a shutdown. (0)
wrapperStopProcess(0) called.
Sending stop signal to JVM
send a packet STOP : NULL
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
shutdownJVM(0) Thread:Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOPPED : 0
read a packet STOPPED : 0
JVM signalled that it was stopped.
Closing socket.
socket read no code (closed?).
server listening on port 32002.
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook complete
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false, exitCode=null
WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.
JVM exited normally.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Service
Using tick timer.
server listening on port 32000.
Launching a JVM...
command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\java.exe" -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms3m -Xmx3m -Djava.library.path="./lib" -classpath "../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar;../../lib/sonar-application-5.3.jar" -Dwrapper.key="dvwrESWxTion4Weh" -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.debug="TRUE" -Dwrapper.pid=4304 -Dwrapper.version="3.2.3" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.service="TRUE" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.sonar.application.App
JVM started (PID=376)
WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main  Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
Running a 64-bit JVM.
Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.
Loading native library failed: wrapper-windows-x86-64.dll  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-windows-x86-64 in java.library.path
Loaded native library: wrapper.dll
Calling native initialization method.
Initializing WrapperManager native library.
Java Executable: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\java.exe
Windows version: 6.3.9600
Java Version   : 1.8.0_72-b15 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation

Control event monitor thread started.
Startup runner thread started.
WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@4f023edb, args[]) called by thread: main
Communications runner thread started.
Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
Opened Socket from 31000 to 32000
Send a packet KEY : dvwrESWxTion4Weh
handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32000,localport=31000])
accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31000
read a packet KEY : dvwrESWxTion4Weh
Got key from JVM: dvwrESWxTion4Weh
send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
send a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Start Application.
send a packet START : start
Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
PingTimeout from Wrapper is 0
Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Received a packet START : start
calling WrapperListener.start()
Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOP : 0
Startup runner thread stopped.
read a packet STOP : 0
JVM requested a shutdown. (0)
wrapperStopProcess(0) called.
Sending stop signal to JVM
send a packet STOP : NULL
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
shutdownJVM(0) Thread:Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOPPED : 0
read a packet STOPPED : 0
JVM signalled that it was stopped.
Closing socket.
socket read no code (closed?).
server listening on port 32002.
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook complete
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false, exitCode=null
WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.
JVM exited normally.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

When running from the console using "StartSonar.bat" the following lines appear before sonar starts up which don't appear when running as a service

```
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
2016.02.09 09:14:11 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\sonarqube-5.3\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Users\t8239\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process7650225466698856396properties
2016.02.09 09:14:11 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2016.02.09 09:14:11 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
```

Is there's some sort of forking privilige required to start sonar through the wrapper ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the windows service user added locally and given desktop interaction priviliges I can now start the SonarQube service.

Answer (score 0):

Configure SonarQube service to not use the Local System account, but another user with more privileges.

See 
 [Running SonarQube as a Service on Windows](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Running+SonarQube+as+a+Service+on+Windows) 
[Migrate SonarQube from Tomcat to a Windows service](http://qualilogy.com/en/migrate-sonarqube-tomcat-to-windows-service/)

Comment: This is basically the correct answer but the problem was I didn't know which privileges were missing.  It turns out giving desktop interaction permissions to the user allows it to work.  I think this is because the wrapper needs this to fork the java process

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which doesn't require changing the user from LocalSystem or giving additional privileges, is to **specify the complete path to the `java.exe` binary in `conf\wrapper.conf`**. Example:

```
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe
```

The hypothesis by andyd that the wrapper fails at forking the Java process is exactly what happened in my case, as an error message in the log file (in `logs\sonar.log`) reveals.

Specifying a normal user account was not a practical solution in my case because of the corporate password policy, which requires a password change every few weeks.